# javascript (making collage from images)

Tags: javascript, jquery

### javascript code for making collage through images working in mozilla but chrome

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var canvaswidth = $('.rc-contentholder').width();
    var canvasheight = $('.rc-contentholder').height();

    function setleftandtop(noofdivision) {

        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('rc-singlecontentholder');
        var noofelements = elements.length;
        //place the first row
        currentelementid = elements[0].id;
        $("#" + currentelementid).css('left', '0px');
        $("#" + currentelementid).css('top', '0px');

        for (j = 1; j < noofdivision; j++) {

            previousleft = parseFloat(elements[j - 1].style.left);
            top = 0;
            previouswidth = parseFloat(elements[j - 1].style.width);

            elements[j].style.left = (previousleft + previouswidth) + "px";

            elements[j].style.top = 0;

        }
        //place the remaining rows
        for (i = noofdivision; i < noofelements; i++) {
            currentid = elements[i - noofdivision].id;

            left = parseFloat(elements[i - noofdivision].style.left);

            uppertop = parseFloat(elements[i - noofdivision].style.top);
            console.log(uppertop)
            height = $("#" + currentid).height();
            console.log("id" + "=" + currentid + " " + "height" + "=" + ($("#" + currentid).height()));
            elements[i].style.left = left + "px";

            elements[i].style.top = (uppertop + height) + "px";

        }

    }

    if (canvaswidth >= 1200) {
        noofdivision = 5;
        singlecontentholderwidth = canvaswidth / noofdivision;
        $('.rc-singlecontentholder').css('width', singlecontentholderwidth);
        setleftandtop(noofdivision);
    } else if (canvaswidth >= 900) {
        noofdivision = 4;
        singlecontentholderwidth = canvaswidth / noofdivision;
        $('.rc-singlecontentholder').css('width', singlecontentholderwidth);
        setleftandtop(noofdivision);
    } else if (canvaswidth >= 550) {
        noofdivision = 3;
        singlecontentholderwidth = canvaswidth / noofdivision;
        $('.rc-singlecontentholder').css('width', singlecontentholderwidth);
        setleftandtop(noofdivision);
    } else if (canvaswidth >= 480) {
        noofdivision = 2
        singlecontentholderwidth = canvaswidth / noofdivision;
        $('.rc-singlecontentholder').css('width', singlecontentholderwidth);
        setleftandtop(noofdivision);
    } else if (canvaswidth < 480) {
        noofdivision = 1;
        singlecontentholderwidth = canvaswidth / noofdivision;
        $('.rc-singlecontentholder').css('width', singlecontentholderwidth);
        setleftandtop(noofdivision);
    }
});
```

in chrome the height of the division rc-singlecontentholder keeps changing dont know what is happening please help me. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for easier troubleshooting? (jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb you should always provide a standalone example/snippet/jsfiddle, so it is easy for others to figure out exactly what your problem is. In your code the markup(HTML) is missing and several of your variables are not defined. However I will try to give you a push in the right direction from the information you have provided.

I deduced that you want to determine the amount of images your canvas can fit from an element with class 'rc-containerwidth'. The first thing I want to address is that if you iterate from

```
var j = 0
```

you can just use

```
elements[j]
```

but this is just a minor esthetic.

I am assuming that you have classes called 'rc-singlecontentholder' with actual content, that would make the divs have a width and a height. With this in mind the real problem I see with your code is that the first for loop sets the first n=(noofdivision-1) elements with class 'rc-singlecontentholder' to have top=0.

The second for loop starts at element number n=i-noofdivison. Since it starts at

```
var i = noofdivison;
```

this effectively starts at n=0, which means you are looping over the same elements as in the first loop. You then calculate the variable upperTop as the elements top position which will be 0.

```
upperTop = top = 0;
```

and finally sets the top of this element as top + height

```
elements[i].style.top = (upperTop + height) + 'px';
```

Which will cause the different elements to be positioned at the height of their container. This will happen to the first n=(noofdivison-1) elements and the rest will be placed depending on what your original css for these elements are, which are hard to guess from your question. These factors coupled together is likely what is causing the height in chrome to be different from the height of the divs in firefox. Hope this can point you in the right direction to bandage your code.

There are several improvements that can be done to the code apart from this, but this could be a good task to solve if you are in the stages of learning JavaScript.

If learning JavaScript is not of the essence then I suggest trying to reuse some of the libraries that already exists for image collages, which should be more robust and time-saving than creating your own.
You can check out one alternative called [H5P Collage](https://h5p.org/collage) or check out how we used JavaScript to make it at [github](https://github.com/h5p/h5p-collage). Disclosure: I am one of the developers on the [H5P team](https://h5p.org/).